# I'm looking for the right term of matrix by matrix multiplication that return scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

I mean what is the mane of the following operation

For square matrix $A,B$

$$ A ? B = \sum_{i,j}a_{i,j} b_{i,j} = Tr(A^T B)    $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume the matrices are real, then it’s a common matrix inner product called the Frobenius inner product: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product?wprov=sfti1